# dojo widget already registered

Tags: dojo, widget, registry, destroy

I am getting a [widget is already registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apB8x.jpg) error when running this code using the Dojo library.

[image]

In the console I can see that there is a widget with this ID, but I cannot destroy it.

```
function layoutDialog2(data, taskBoard, idName)
{ 
    var _idName = idName;
    var _taskBoard = taskBoard;
    var d = addDialog(); //dialog
    var idD = d.get("id"); //random ID
    var f = addNew(d, Form, {id: "f"+idD, style: "border: 1px solid red"});
    var c = addNew(d, ContentPane, {id: "cp"+idD});    

    for (var i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        var l1 = addNew2(f, "label", {style: "1px solid green"});
        var span1 = addNew2(l1, "span", {innerHTML: "a"+i+": "});
        var t1 = addNew(l1, TextBox, {name: "a"+i, value: data["a"+i]});
        var br1 = addNew2(l1, "br", {});        
    }

    var b1 = addNew(c, Button, {label: "Change", onClick: function() { change(); }});
    var b2 = addNew(c, Button, {label: "DELETE", onClick: function() { deleteTask(); }});

    function change()
    {
        console.log(_taskBoard);
        _taskBoard.destroyRecursive(); 
        console.log(_taskBoard);

        var v1 = registry.byId("f"+idD); //get form value
        var v1 = v1.get("value");
        layoutTask(v1);
        _taskBoard.destroyRecursive();
    }

    function deleteTask()
    {
        _taskBoard.destroyRecursive();
    }

    d.show();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error, or at least specifically what `ID` it says is registered? What do you mean by "I can not destroy it"? Are you getting another error for that as well?

Comment: This happened to me when I had bad order-of-operations with various `dojo/domReady!` and `dojo/ready` calls. Make sure your parsing and accessing is in order. Simplify, simplify, simplify, then debug from there.

Comment: thanks, but dojo makes me mad!

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear the registry of any IDs of Dijits that were already created.  On my project, we created a helper function to do this for us:

```
destroyFieldsByIdArray: function (fieldIdArray) {
                var i,
                    idToDestroy;
                for (i = 0; i < fieldIdArray.length; i += 1) {
                    idToDestroy = fieldIdArray[i];
                    if (dijit.byId(idToDestroy)) {
                        dijit.byId(idToDestroy).destroyRecursive(true);
                    }
                }
            }
```